# Parsing Docopt commands into components

Tags: python, regex, parsing, docopt

I have a command which I use in [docopt](http://docopt.org/) which looks like this:

```
cli.py argument_test (--required_id=<required_id> | --required_name=<required_name>) (--required=<required>) (--repeat=<repeat>)... (--required_named=<required_named> | <required_named>) (--thisflag | --thatflag) [--optionalflag] [--optional_named=<optional_named>]
```

I need some way of parsing this into a structure which could present the information like this (on a web page for example)

```
RequiredArguments: required_id or requiredname, required, repeat(list), required_named, thisflag(bool) or thatflag(bool)

OptionalArguments: optionalflag(bool), optionalnamed
```

[image: bad ms paint image of what command might look like on a webpage]

Docopt parses the pattern into an object with children which looks like the following:

```
Required(Command('argument_test', False), Required(Either(Option(None, '--required_id', 1, None), Option(None, '--required_name', 1, None))), Required(Option(None, '--required', 1, None)), OneOrMore(Required(Option(None, '--repeat', 1, []))), Required(Either(Option(None, '--required_named', 1, None), Argument('<required_named>', None))), Required(Either(Option(None, '--thisflag', 0, False), Option(None, '--thatflag', 0, False))), Optional(Option(None, '--optionalflag', 0, False)), Optional(Option(None, '--optional_named', 1, None)))))
```

I'm pretty stumped where to go from here in how I should go about parsing these. Any advice is appreciated!